# Клавиатура поднимает всю разметку вверх

Tags: android, клавиатура

Есть разметка с `EditText`. При фокусе на него клавиатура толкает весь контент внизу и сжимает его. Нужно чтобы она просто выдвигалась поверх всего. Я так понял, тут `windowSoftInputMode` не причём. Как это сделать? Разметка содержит view-элементы с высотой по весу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте в манифест к активити, в которой это должно быть, добавить параметр `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

```
<activity
  android:name="your.MainActivity"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Подробнее [здесь.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: Вот я идиот)) знал же о нем )